# Setup an ETCD cluster behind an ELB using EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb, rancher, etcd

I am new to Kubernetes and have a requirement in which have to setup an ETCD cluster behind an ELB. Our K8s cluster will be hosted using Rancher. Can anyone please share the steps or link for the same.

Comment: etcd.io and https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#multi-node-etcd-cluster-with-load-balancer

Comment: It's not clear if you're using this etcd for Kubernetes or for external services, or if you want to run it inside of a Kubernetes cluster but still use it for external services. Can you share more about why you want it behind an ELB? If it's for Kubernetes, you don't need an ELB in the mix.

Comment: @monachus I am using it for kubernetes cluster but want to keep etcd as an external entity not to be managed using rancher. So that in case any etcd node goes down, kube API server should not try reaching it and doesn't restart.

Comment: I don't think that's possible for clusters deployed from within Rancher, but you can deploy an RKE cluster with an external etcd resource and then import it into Rancher: https://rancher.com/docs/rke/latest/en/config-options/services/external-etcd/

Comment: I setup the Kubernetes cluster using RKE, seems we cannot setup using rancher cli. I have setup an external load balancer in front of etcd and passed the LB URL to rke config file and it worked. Thanks a lot @monachus for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1: If you will import cluster into rancher, then @suren is right. You basically need to create Kubernetes cluster that comforms all of your needs then import that into Rancher.

2: If you plan to launch clusters using Rancher, then you need to create [NodeTemplate](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/user-settings/node-templates/) that uses AWS EC2 for etcd nodes. Then you can launch cluster by ticking master, etcd and worker nodes separately and reference your etcd `NodeTemplate` in etcd node group.